# Upper bound of conditional mutual information

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

Given random variables $X$,$Y$ with a joint distribution $P(X,Y)$ and another random variable $Z$, it is known that there are cases when the conditional mutual information $I(X;Y|Z)$ is greater than mutual information $I(X;Y)$.

For example, let $Y = X + Z$ and $X \perp Z$. It could be shown that:
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z) = H(Y|Z) = H(X) \geq I(X;Y).
\end{align}
**However, what is the upper bound of $I(X;Y|Z)$ given $X$ and $Y$?** We want to solve the following problem:
$$ \sup_Z I(X;Y|Z),
$$
where $Z$ is any random variable.

An upper bound (not necessarily tight) of $I(X;Y|Z)$ could be readily obtained as:
\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z) &= I(X;Y,Z) - I(X;Z) \\
&= H(X)  - H(X|Y,Z) - I(X;Z) \\
&\leq H(X).
\end{align}
With symmetry, we also have $I(X;Y|Z) \leq H(Y)$. To summarize,
$$ I(X;Y|Z) \leq \min\{ H(X),H(Y)\}.
$$
However, could the inequality above be an equality? **Or else, for any given random variables $X$,$Y$ (with given joint distribution $P(X,Y)$), is there an exact solution to $\sup_Z I(X;Y|Z)$**?

Comment: Could you recall what $I(X;Y)$ and $I(X;Y)|Z)$ mean?

Comment: $I(X;Y) := H(Y) - H(Y|X)$. $I(X;Y|Z) := H(Y|Z) - H(Y|X,Z).$ Here $H(\cdot)$ denotes the Shannon entropy while $H(\cdot|\cdot)$ denotes the conditional Shannon entropy defined as $H(Y|X) = \mathbb E_{x\sim X} \left[ H(Y|X=x)\right]$.